# Why does ng-click not fire functions when inside ng-repeat, in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am working on a small AngularJS application. In one of the views, I have replaced some hard-coded html with data coming from a JSON file that I iterate through:

```
<class="actions-list">
    <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.myCustomService.config.items"
         ng-class="{'disabled': !item.isEanabled}"
         class="actions-item"
         ng-click="$ctrl.selectAction('{{item.action}}')">
      {{item.name | translate }}
    </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that, since this replacement, the function fired by `ng-click`, that used to be (hard-coded) `ng-click="$ctrl.selectAction('register');` and so on, does not work anymore.

Why does that happen? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes or `{{ }}` inside `ng-click`:

```
<class="actions-list">
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.myCustomService.config.items"
     ng-class="{'disabled': !item.isEanabled}"
     class="actions-item"
     ng-click="$ctrl.selectAction(item.action)">
  {{item.name | translate }}
</div>
```

Comment: If you created a reproducable example(jsfiddle for example) it would be easier for someone to understand the problem and help with it